# Reversing an order of integers produced by recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have a basic recursion function that will essentially print out a line of numbers given one input number.

```
def formula1(distance):
    if distance == 1:
        print(int(distance))
        return
    elif (distance % 2) == 0:
        print(int(distance), end=" ")
        return formula1(distance / 2)
    elif (distance % 2) == 1:
        print(int(distance), end=" ")
        return formula1(3*distance + 1)
```

I have to print the number in reverse now, without it being a string or list. I'm really unsure how do do this, declaring a new temporary variable would just get overwritten. And defining a variable in the parameters wouldn't help I think...

In the above function obviously the print() lines would have to be removed, but I'm not sure what to replace it with without trying to figure out the whole calculation backwards.

Example,
formula1 (5) prints out `5 16 8 4 2 1`
I need it to print out `1 2 4 8 16 5`

Comment: Please provide some sample output as well as what you are trying to achieve (an example).

Comment: If you meant to do recursion here, the it is very poorly implemented. First of all, the function returns different "things" under different cases. Second, there is no usage of the returned value by the calling function (i.e., it is "scrapped"; what's the point in returning it then???).

Comment: rather than printing as you go, you could return an array and just print that. Might be easier to think about.

Comment: Thou shalt not use `==` with non integer types.

Comment: Use `distance // 2` to ensure that the result of the division is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to ensure that the recursive call is made prior to the call to `print`:

```
def formula1(distance):
    if distance == 1:
        print(distance, end=" ")
        return
    elif (distance % 2) == 0:
        v = formula1(distance // 2)
        print(distance, end=" ")
        return v
    else:
        v = formula1(3 * distance + 1)
        print(distance, end=" ")
        return v
```

Each call to `formula1` has its own local scope, so the assignments to `v` are distinct and preserved once a recursive call returns.